# Linq To Twitter add members to media/image

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I have been playing with the Linq To Twitter module and it has been working fine for automating everything we have needed to do so far.

The problem I have now run into - I want to upload an image file and tag "who's in this photo" some of my followers.

I want to use LTT to do this as I only want to tag members from certain geographic locations. I am able to use LTT to upload pictures to my twitter account. I am able to retrieve the geographical locations of my followers.

How can I tag a follower in the picture and then upload it to twitter using LTT? I may have the wrong terminology, but in the twitter web page they call it - "Tagged in this photo" or "Tagged users".